# How to avoid duplicate names of methods Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created method that listen to form controls value changes and returns stream of calculated duration

```
export class AppComponent  {
  control1 = new FormControl()
  control2 = new FormControl();

  public calculatedDuration$: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculatedDuration$ = this.calculateDuration()
  }

  private calculateDuration(): Observable<number> {
    return combineLatest([this.control1.valueChanges, this.control2.valueChanges]).pipe(
        map(([frequency, quantity]) => {
          return this.service.calculateDuration(frequency, quantity)
        })
    )
  }
}
```

So far so good, naming method make sense  stream is being mapped to the calculated duration.

But I would like to introduce method that calculates duration but doesn't wrap in an observable like so

```
  private calculateDuration(frequency, quantity): number {
    return this.service.calculateDuration(frequnecy, quantity)
  }
```

And may be replace logic in the `map`

```
  private calculateDuration(): Observable<number> {
    return combineLatest([this.control1.valueChanges, this.control2.valueChanges]).pipe(
        map(([frequency, quantity]) => {
          return this.calculateDuration(frequency, quantity)
        })
    )
  }
```

The question is - how I'm suppose to name methods that do the same thing?

Comment: Perhaps methods that return Observables, can be named with a word `observe`. For example in your case: `observeDuration()`. I don't think there is the right answer but it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is adding a `$` after the variables/methods name that return an `Observable`.
I think it's a convenient naming convention to distinguish `values` from `streams`.

```ts
private calculateDuration(frequency, quantity): number {
  return this.service.calculateDuration(frequency, quantity);
}

private calculateDuration$(): Observable<number> {
  const source = [this.control1.valueChanges, this.control2.valueChanges];

  return combineLatest(sources).pipe(
    map(([frequency, quantity]) => {
      return this.calculateDuration(frequency, quantity);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would work for `this.calculatedDuration$ = this.calculateDuration$()`
But won't work for `this.isDurationCustom$ = this.isDurationCustom$()`